# Swift Array to AnyObject Errors

Tags: objective-c, swift, typhoon

I'm having multiple errors trying to return an array from a function with swift.

If I do this:

```
private dynamic func rootHomePageViewController() -> AnyObject? {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(RootHomePageViewController.self) {
        (definition) in
        definition.useInitializer("style:navigationOrientation:options:") {
            (initializer) in
            initializer.injectParameterWith(UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.Scroll.rawValue)            // must convert to raw value - watch for errors here
            initializer.injectParameterWith(UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation.Vertical.rawValue)    // must convert to raw value - watch for errors here
            initializer.injectParameterWith(nil)
        }
        definition.injectMethod("setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:", parameters: {
            (method) in
            method.injectParameterWith([self.pageViewController1(),self.pageViewController2(),self.pageViewController3()])
            method.injectParameterWith(UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward.rawValue)
            method.injectParameterWith(false)
            method.injectParameterWith(nil)
        })
    }
}
```

I get the error: `Cannot convert the expression's type '$T11' to type 'AnyObject?'`

Note, `self.pageViewController1()` returns AnyObject? as do each of the other 2 functions

If I replace the array `method.injectParameterWith(self.rootHomePageViewControllerPages)` there with this function (to create an array):

```
private dynamic func rootHomePageViewControllerPages() -> [AnyObject] {
    return [self.pageViewController1(),self.pageViewController2(),self.pageViewController3()] as [AnyObject]!
}
```

I get the error: `Cannot convert the expression's type 'Array' to type 'AnyObject?'`

No matter what I do, I cannot get the function to return correctly (Replaying `[AnyObject]` with `AnyObject?` , etc.

Basically all i'm trying to do is inject the array to `viewControllers` of `UIPageViewController`, but there is some issue with converting arrays.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Since we're doing reflection/meta-programming, it must pass through the ObjC runtimne. Swift arrays are normally bridged to NSArray, transparently. But try explicitly making an NSArray. eg NSArray.withObjects(a, b, c, d, nil)

Comment: Also what are self.pageViewController1(), self.pageController2() ? Do these methods return TyphoonDefinition?

Comment: I thought I had included them. They do return TyphoonDefinition (though the function is actually AnyObject). Will try NSArray.withObjects now.

Comment: if you make an answer for your questions it might help other users. Also helps us do good support since we can see what issues don't have answers.

Comment: Done. I actually had to remove them as returning their respective types, because it was returning a `TyphoonDefinition` and couldn't cast it to the class. (see answer)

Comment: Yes, in Swift the return type must be `AnyObject` to satisfy its strict type checking both before and after activation of the assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this array issue using:

```
private dynamic func pageViewControllers() -> [AnyObject!] {
    return [self.createViewController1(),self.createViewController2(),self.createViewController3()] as [AnyObject!]
}
```

Where each `createViewController()` function returns `AnyObject!`:

```
private dynamic func createViewController1() -> AnyObject! {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(TableViewController.self) {
        (definition) in
        definition.scope = TyphoonScope.Singleton
    }
}
```